# Unable to run the app on iOS Simulator due to NSPOSIXErrorDomain error

Tags: xcode, flutter, ios-simulator

When I'm trying to run my app (a Flutter app) on the iOS simulator I get the following error:

> Unable to install /[Path]/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on
> 3597CFAA-C3AA-444E-94A9-826F707ED584. This is sometimes caused by a
> malformed plist file: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: An
> error was encountered processing the command
> (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=63): copyfile of
> file:///[Path]/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app/ to
> file:///[AnotherPath]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3597CFAA-C3AA-444E-94A9-826F707ED584/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoordinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/ED6E3554-BEDD-45EF-B787-DB32CB50AADB/Runner.app
> failed: File name too long Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain,
> code 63

I have tried cleaning `DataDriven` folder, `Clean Build Folder` from XCdoe, regenerating the workspace file, nothing works but I can run the app on the device.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: I've been having this issue for days now, found a solution?

Comment: @YassinSameh I removed the flutter installation folder, fetched again from the repo and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, for me what worked was deleting all hidden files in the project besides git related ones, .idea, .packages etc.. As well as podspec.lock and the build folder manually.

Answer (score 3):

- delete → Runner.xcworkspace → xcuserdata folder
- delete → Pods folder on inside ios folder
- delete → ios → flutter → Flutter.podspec
- run flutter clean
- flutter run